# Make all fields in an interface readonly in a nested way

Tags: typescript, nested, readonly, readonly-attribute

I know that, we can use *Readonly< T>* to redeclare all fields of *T* as readonly, as in: [[Typescript: extending an interface and redeclaring the existing fields as readonly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41201198/typescript-extending-an-interface-and-redeclaring-the-existing-fields-as-readon][1])

What about nested fields? For example:

```
interface School {
  teachers: Array<Teacher>;
  students: Array<Student>;
}

interface Teacher {
  teacherId: number;
  personInfo: PersonInfo;
}

interface Student {
  studentId: number;
  personInfo: PersonInfo;
}

interface PersonInfo {
  name: string;
  age: number
}
```

How to create a SchoolReadonly type, in which all nested fields are readonly.

A simple test case:

```
var s: SchoolReadonly = {
  teachers: [{teacherId: 1, personInfo: {name: "John", age: 40}}],
  students: [{studentId: 1, personInfo: {name: "Dan", age: 20}}]
}

s.teachers[0].personInfo.name = "John2"; //should produce readonly error
s.students[0].personInfo.age = 22; //should produce readonly error
```

As a constraint, I do not want to add *Readonly* directly to the School, Teacher, Student and PersonInfo interfaces.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [DeepReadonly Object Typescript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879327/deepreadonly-object-typescript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use generics and type aliases, it's a lot of code, but it will do the trick:

```
interface School<T extends Teacher<PersonInfo>, S extends Student<PersonInfo>> {
    teachers: Array<T>;
    students: Array<S>;
}

type EditableSchool = School<EditableTeacher, EditableStudent>;
type ReadonlySchool = Readonly<School<ReadonlyTeacher, ReadonlyStudent>>;

interface Teacher<P extends PersonInfo> {
    teacherId: number;
    personInfo: P;
}

type EditableTeacher = Teacher<PersonInfo>;
type ReadonlyTeacher = Readonly<Teacher<Readonly<PersonInfo>>>;

interface Student<P extends PersonInfo> {
    studentId: number;
    personInfo: P;
}

type EditableStudent = Student<PersonInfo>;
type ReadonlyStudent = Readonly<Student<Readonly<PersonInfo>>>;

interface PersonInfo {
    name: string;
    age: number
}

var s: ReadonlySchool = {
  teachers: [{teacherId: 1, personInfo: {name: "John", age: 40}}],
  students: [{studentId: 1, personInfo: {name: "Dan", age: 20}}]
}

s.teachers = null;
s.teachers[0].personInfo.name = "John2"; // Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a constant or a read-only property
s.students[0].personInfo.age = 22; // Cannot assign to 'age' because it is a constant or a read-only property
```

([code in playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html#src=interface%20School%3CT%20extends%20Teacher%3CPersonInfo%3E%2C%20S%20extends%20Student%3CPersonInfo%3E%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20teachers%3A%20Array%3CT%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20students%3A%20Array%3CS%3E%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20EditableSchool%20%3D%20School%3CEditableTeacher%2C%20EditableStudent%3E%3B%0Atype%20ReadonlySchool%20%3D%20Readonly%3CSchool%3CReadonlyTeacher%2C%20ReadonlyStudent%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20Teacher%3CP%20extends%20PersonInfo%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20teacherId%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20personInfo%3A%20P%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20EditableTeacher%20%3D%20Teacher%3CPersonInfo%3E%3B%0Atype%20ReadonlyTeacher%20%3D%20Readonly%3CTeacher%3CReadonly%3CPersonInfo%3E%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20Student%3CP%20extends%20PersonInfo%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20studentId%3A%20number%3B%0A%20%20%20%20personInfo%3A%20P%3B%0A%7D%0A%0Atype%20EditableStudent%20%3D%20Student%3CPersonInfo%3E%3B%0Atype%20ReadonlyStudent%20%3D%20Readonly%3CStudent%3CReadonly%3CPersonInfo%3E%3E%3E%3B%0A%0Ainterface%20PersonInfo%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20name%3A%20string%3B%0A%20%20%20%20age%3A%20number%0A%7D%0A%0Avar%20s%3A%20ReadonlySchool%20%3D%20%7B%0A%20%20teachers%3A%20%5B%7BteacherId%3A%201%2C%20personInfo%3A%20%7Bname%3A%20%22John%22%2C%20age%3A%2040%7D%7D%5D%2C%0A%20%20students%3A%20%5B%7BstudentId%3A%201%2C%20personInfo%3A%20%7Bname%3A%20%22Dan%22%2C%20age%3A%2020%7D%7D%5D%0A%7D%0A%0As.teachers%20%3D%20null%3B%0As.teachers%5B0%5D.personInfo.name%20%3D%20%22John2%22%3B%20%2F%2F%20Cannot%20assign%20to%20'name'%20because%20it%20is%20a%20constant%20or%20a%20read-only%20property%0As.students%5B0%5D.personInfo.age%20%3D%2022%3B%20%2F%2F%20Cannot%20assign%20to%20'age'%20because%20it%20is%20a%20constant%20or%20a%20read-only%20property))

---

#### Edit

If you want `s.teachers[0] = nul` to fail then you need to also change the `Array` to `ReadonlyArray`, so:

```
interface School<T extends Teacher<PersonInfo>, Ta extends ArrayLike<T>, S extends Student<PersonInfo>, Ts extends ArrayLike<S>> {
    teachers: Ta;
    students: Ts;
}

type EditableSchool = School<EditableTeacher, Array<EditableTeacher>, EditableStudent, Array<EditableStudent>>;
type ReadonlySchool = Readonly<School<ReadonlyTeacher, ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyTeacher>, ReadonlyStudent, ReadonlyArray<ReadonlyStudent>>>;
```

The rest is the same, but then:

```
s.teachers = null; // Cannot assign to 'teachers' because it is a constant or a read-only property
s.teachers[0] = null; // Index signature in type 'ReadonlyArray<Readonly<Teacher<Readonly<PersonInfo>>>>' only permits reading
```

True, it's not a simple solution and is very verbose, but I don't think that a simple generic solution exists, at least for now, for the problem.
Consider:

```
type ReadyonlyDeep<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: ReadyonlyDeep<T[P]>;
}
```

This works great as long as the object has only other simple objects:

```
interface A {
    b: B
}

interface B {
    str: string;
}

let a: ReadyonlyDeep<A>;
a.b.str = "fe"; // Cannot assign to 'str' because it is a constant or a read-only property
```

But if you introduce an array:

```
interface B {
    str: string;
    moreB: B[];
}
```

Then:

```
a.b.moreB = []; // Cannot assign to 'moreB' because it is a constant or a read-only property
a.b.moreB[0].str = "hey"; // this is fine though
```

It probably isn't an easy problem to solve.

Comment: Isn't there an easier and more generic way?