# DeepReadonly Object Typescript

Tags: typescript, immutability

It is possible to create a `DeepReadonly` type like this:

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
  readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>;
};

interface A {
  B: { C: number; };
  D: { E: number; }[];
}

const myDeepReadonlyObject: DeepReadonly<A> = {
  B: { C: 1 },
  D: [ { E: 2 } ],
}

myDeepReadonlyObject.B = { C: 2 }; // error :)
myDeepReadonlyObject.B.C = 2; // error :)
```

This is great. Both `B` and `B.C` are readonly. When I try to modify `D` however...

```
// I'd like this to be an error
myDeepReadonlyObject.D[0] = { E: 3 }; // no error :(
```

How should I write `DeepReadonly` so that nested arrays are readonly as well?

Comment: I'm not getting an error for `console.log(myDeepReadonlyObject.D[0]);` Which version of typescript are you using?

Comment: I had the "noImplicitAny" flag set in my tsconfig. The question still stands, however. I've updated it to be more clear. Thanks.

Comment: For those interested, `DeepReadonly` is part of `ts-essentials` package. Check it out: https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials

Answer (score 35):

As of TypeScript 2.8, this is now possible and actually an example in the PR for Conditional Types: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21316

Also see the notes on type inference for Conditional Types:
https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/21496

I modified the example slightly to use the type inference for the readonly array value type because I find `(infer R)[]` clearer than `Array<T[number]>` but both syntaxes work. I also removed the example `NonFunctionPropertyNames` bit as I want to preserve functions in my output.

```
type DeepReadonly<T> =
    T extends (infer R)[] ? DeepReadonlyArray<R> :
    T extends Function ? T :
    T extends object ? DeepReadonlyObject<T> :
    T;

interface DeepReadonlyArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<DeepReadonly<T>> {}

type DeepReadonlyObject<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>;
};
```

Doing DeepReadonly this way also preserves optional fields (thanks to Mariusz for letting me know), e.g.:

```
interface A {
    x?: number;
    y: number;
}

type RA = DeepReadonly<A>;

// RA is effectively typed as such:
interface RA {
    readonly x?: number;
    readonly y: number;
}
```

While TS still has some easy ways to lose "readonly-ness" in certain scenarios, this is as close to a C/C++ style `const` value as you will get.

Comment: Nice answer. 

But when I run your code in TS 1.8.1 after doing `type RA = DeepReadonly<A>;` the `RA` type is equivalent (shows in vs code when hovering over with mouse) to `interface RA {
    readonly x?: number | undefined;
    readonly y: number;
}` and `x` can be omitted.

Comment: Thanks! That's strange, I had an error earlier, but I was tweaking the code as I wrote this answer. I will modify the answer to remove that bit. But the result is even better, so that's good. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: Thanks! 
Why is DeepReadonlyArray even necessary? Since every Array is an object, shouldn't DeepReadonlyObject do? 
Why is the ` T extends Function ? T ` necessary? Lets not remove functions, but couldn't we just leave this condition out?

Comment: @BenCarp While in JS Arrays are indeed just objects with numeric keys, TS has typed Arrays as more strict interfaces and makes them not directly interchangeable. The subscript operators for each are different, etc. The separate clause for functions is there as they are just passed through this type transformation as is, and is needed as otherwise the object test following it will try to transform the function value. It's mostly that the quirks of JS as expressed in TS types are very visible in this type :)

Comment: oh, btw, for anyone interested, I've codified this interface and some helpers in an NPM package here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/@stardazed/deep-readonly

Comment: Doesn't work at all

Answer (score 27):

In addition to zenmumbler [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49670389/4858777), since TypeScript 3.7 is released, [recursive type aliases](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#more-recursive-type-aliases) are now supported and it allows us to improve the solution:

```js
type ImmutablePrimitive = undefined | null | boolean | string | number | Function;

export type Immutable<T> =
    T extends ImmutablePrimitive ? T :
    T extends Array<infer U> ? ImmutableArray<U> :
    T extends Map<infer K, infer V> ? ImmutableMap<K, V> :
    T extends Set<infer M> ? ImmutableSet<M> : ImmutableObject<T>;

export type ImmutableArray<T> = ReadonlyArray<Immutable<T>>;
export type ImmutableMap<K, V> = ReadonlyMap<Immutable<K>, Immutable<V>>;
export type ImmutableSet<T> = ReadonlySet<Immutable<T>>;
export type ImmutableObject<T> = { readonly [K in keyof T]: Immutable<T[K]> };
```

You may notice that instead of extending the base interfaces, as the old solution does, like `interface ImmutableArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<Immutable<T>> {}`, we refer them directly like `type ImmutableArray<T> = ReadonlyArray<Immutable<T>>`.

The old solution works pretty well in most cases, but there are few problems because of replacing original types. For example, if you use [immer](https://github.com/immerjs/immer) and pass the old implementation of `ImmutableArray` to the `produce` function, the draft will lack of array methods like `push()`.

There is also the [issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13923) on GitHub about adding DeepReadonly type to TypeScript.

Comment: This doesn't work with union types: `const doesntwork: Immutable<['one'|'two', 1 | 2]> = [1, 2];`, while the solution from Dmytro Shyryayev does

Answer (score 17):

You might want to use [ts-essentials](https://github.com/krzkaczor/ts-essentials) package for that:

```
import { DeepReadonly } from "ts-essentials";

const myDeepReadonlyObject: DeepReadonly<A> = {
  B: { C: 1 },
  D: [ { E: 2 } ],
}
```

Answer (score 8):

I think this is a better solution:

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: This works because it recursivly calls the type-'function' on the key-property... there is a pretty neat 5min youtube video explaining pretty much this exact usecase... although his solution is a bit better with an additional check, like type MyReadonly<TInput> = { readonly [Key in keyof TInput]: TInput[Key] extends object ? MyReadonly<TInput[Key]>: TInput[Key]; }      
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U1EygIpjAEM

Answer (score 2):

```
export type DR<T> = DeepReadonly<T>

type DeepReadonly<T> =
// tslint:disable-next-line: ban-types
    T extends  AnyFunction | Primitive ? T :
    T extends ReadonlyArray<infer R> ? IDRArray<R> :
    T extends ReadonlyMap<infer K, infer V> ? IDRMap<K, V> :
    T extends ReadonlySet<infer ItemType>? ReadonlySetDeep<ItemType>:
    T extends object ? DRObject<T> :
    T


export type Primitive =
| null
| undefined
| string
| number
| boolean
| symbol
| bigint

export type AnyFunction = (...args: any[]) => any

interface IDRArray<T> extends ReadonlyArray<DeepReadonly<T>> {}

type DRObject<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[P]>;
}

interface IDRMap<K, V> extends ReadonlyMap<DeepReadonly<K>, DeepReadonly<V>> {}

interface ReadonlySetDeep<ItemType>
    extends ReadonlySet<DeepReadonly<ItemType>> {}
```

DeepReadonly generic is a valuable tool that can help enforce immutability.

- I use the short DR name since I use this generic so often.
- `T extends ReadonlyArray<infer R> ?` will be true for both `Array<any>` and `ReadonlyArray<any>`.

Answer (score 1):

You can have a readonly array:

```
interface ReadonlyArray<T> extends Array<T> {
    readonly [n: number]: T;
}
let a = [] as ReadonlyArray<string>;
a[0] = "moo"; // error: Index signature in type 'ReadonlyArray<string>' only permits reading
```

But you can't use it with your solution:

```
interface A {
    B: { C: number; };
    D: ReadonlyArray<{ E: number; }>;
}

myDeepReadonlyObject.D[0] = { E: 3 }; // still fine
```

The type of `D` is `DeepReadonly<ReadonlyArray<{ E: number; }>>` and it won't allow the `ReadonlyArray` to kick in.

I doubt that you'll manage to make it work to objects with arrays in them, you can have either deep read only for arrays or for objects if you want a generic interface/type and not specific ones.
For example, this will work fine:

```
interface A {
    readonly B: { readonly C: number; };
    D: ReadonlyArray<{ E: number; }>;
}

const myDeepReadonlyObject = {
    B: { C: 1 },
    D: [{ E: 2 }],
} as A;

myDeepReadonlyObject.B = { C: 2 }; // error
myDeepReadonlyObject.B.C = 2; // error
myDeepReadonlyObject1.D[0] = { E: 3 }; // error
```

But it has a specific interface to it (`A`) instead of a generic one `DeepReadonly`.

Another option is to use [Immutable.js](https://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) which comes with a builtin definition file and it's pretty easy to use.

Comment: Thanks. It's a real shame this doesn't appear to be possible yet. Anyone have any idea if it's in the works?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [ts-toolbelt](https://github.com/pirix-gh/ts-toolbelt), **it can do operations on types at any depth**

In your case, it would be:

```
import {O} from 'ts-toolbelt'

interface A {
  B: { C: number; };
  D: { E: number; }[];
}

type optional = O.Readonly<A, keyof A, 'deep'>
```

And if you want to compute it deeply (for display purposes), you can use `Compute` for that

Answer (score 1):

```
type DeepReadonly<T> = {
    readonly [Key in keyof T]: T[Key] extends any[] | Record<string, unknown> ? DeepReadonly<T[Key]> : T[Key]
}
```

Comment: I recommend that you don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score -1):

Now you can just use `as const` as it makes readonly for all nested objects

According to https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31856

here is an example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhjAvDA3gKBpmY4FsCmAXDAIwA0GWcA5kapVljgceQ4-LcQEwUdYATOFDjEA2gF12AXzTT4EGKEhQ0auADoa+DUJEaADgFcIACwAUJAJQBuNJu0bm+JDADMdoA

Comment: `as const` is for literals, but the question is about generic types.