# How to create deep readonly type in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to create a type that will make any array/object deeply read-only.
So far I created this type:

```
  type DeepReadonly<G> = G extends Array<infer U> ?
  ReadonlyArray<DeepReadonly<U>> :
  (G extends object ? Readonly<{[p in keyof G]: DeepReadonly<G[p]>}> : G);
```

But I have a problem when the generic type is `any`.
In this case, `DeepReadonly` becomes a union type of all possibilities in the conditional type above including `any`.
Which ends up with **not** read-only type.

For example:

```
let x: DeepReadonly<any> = 1;
x = 2; // no error
```

Is there a type like 'any' that can be defined as readonly in case it's array/object?
Is it possible to achieve what I want in the first place with TypeScript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `never` would be a type you can't assign to .. and it would cause an error  in your case .. but not 100% sure it's waht you are looking for

Comment: why not just use `const x: DeepReadonly<any> = 1;`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I want totally immutable object in TS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43120022/i-want-totally-immutable-object-in-ts)

Answer (score 2):

```
export  type ReadonlyDeep<T> = {
    readonly [P in keyof T]: ReadonlyDeep<T[P]>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the variable can be assigned to because you used a `let`. Using a `let` will always be assignable—that’s what it is for.

```
let x: ...

// This will never be an error for a valid type value, as "let" by definition means that it is assignable.
x = ...
```

To make it so you can’t assign to `x`, you first have to use a `const`.

That said, to your original question, if you pass `any` as the type parameter, you are expressly dipping out of the type system and allowing anything to be assigned to the variable. There is no type definition you can use that will cause `any` to be `readonly any`, which is not a concept that quite makes sense.