# eslint or strongly typed warning when accessing static information from a list

Tags: typescript, eslint

Recently ran into an issue where static information was being overwritten accidentally.

We have an online game where the player can choose from a list of game modes. All relevant settings are stored in static classes that looks like this:

```
export class ModeClassic4PData extends BaseGameModeData {
    premiumExpansionAccess = undefined
    modeSetting = ModeSettingEnum.Base
    extensionSetting = ExtensionSettingEnum.Players4
    optionalGameMechanics = []
    startingSettlementPlacements = [TileEnums.CornerBuildingTypes.Settlement, TileEnums.CornerBuildingTypes.Settlement]
    name = 'Base'
    active = true
    comingSoon = false
    defaultMap = MapSettingEnum.TutorialClassic4P
    defaultPlayerCount = 4
}
```

When a player selects a mode, and starts a game, the information is pulled from a static list.

```
export class GameModeDataController {

    static gameModeDataList: BaseGameModeData[] = [
        new GameMode.ModeClassic4PData(), new GameMode.ModeClassicTutorial4PData(), new GameMode.ModeClassic6PData(), new GameMode.ModeClassic8PData(),

        new GameMode.ModeSeafarersData(), new GameMode.ModeSeafarers6PData(),

        new GameMode.ModeSuperHostPowersData(), new GameMode.ModeTwoVersusTwoData(), new GameMode.ModeCitiesAndKnightsData(), new GameMode.ModeMulticatanData(),
    ]

    static getModeDataForMode(modeSetting: ModeSettingEnum): BaseGameModeData | undefined {
        for(const gameModeData of GameModeDataController.gameModeDataList) {
            if(gameModeData.modeSetting == modeSetting) return gameModeData
        }
        return undefined
    }

}
```

The problem we ran into was that in one scenario, this information was pulled, used to initiate a game variable, then altered later in the game without us making the connection that it was referencing the static member originally pulled from this list.

So, is there a linting method or strongly typed way to prevent accidentally changing listed static members?

---

For now we've gone with the solution of just returning a new instance of the object when pulled. This way any accidental changes doesn't affect the rest which isn't the most efficient.

```
export function newInstanceOfObject<T extends object>(instance: T): T {
    const newInstance = new (instance.constructor as { new (): T })()
    return newInstance
}

static getModeDataForMode(modeSetting: ModeSettingEnum): BaseGameModeData | undefined {
    for(const gameModeData of GameModeDataController.gameModeDataList) {
        if(gameModeData.modeSetting == modeSetting) return newInstanceOfObject(gameModeData)
    }
    return undefined
}
```

Comment: 1. Unlike say, the term "statically typed" the term "strongly typed" has no agreed upon meaning, and it's not clear what you mean by it in this question. 2. Why are you using a class purely as a namespace (only static members)? 3. Why do you have a function that creates a new instance of an instance's constructor? 4. If you're mutating something, and you don't want it "overwritten" then why are you using static properties instead of instance properties? None of this makes any sense. Please strip this down to a minimal repro case to show the *actual* problem you're having.

Comment: @JaredSmith 
1. Here I mean the ability to throw an error or warning when changing values that should be static.
2. Do you have a better suggestion. A structural solution to our problem is also acceptable. We essential have game mode settings that are fixed that we want to pull to properly initiate the game based on player selection. 
3. This was just the 5s solution we found and were able to implementing quickly. Looking for something better. 
4. We accidentally mutated it. It was never intended to be mutated. We are trying to find a way to avoid accidentally doing this again.

Comment: That's not what static means: static means *belongs to the class rather than the instance*, not *is immutable*. Static members are mutable. You want something like this https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oQC5iwS2GgCcBTMAE3gDsQBPaAIzCIC5Msi8qBzAbQF1oAXmi8ARGDEAaaGIZj+qAL6ogA

Comment: ok, I'm not sure what the technical term for what I'm looking for. Here I mean an attribute that is never intended to be mutated. Not supposed to change

Comment: The technical term is "immutable", the TS access modifier is "readonly". See the link I added to my comment and the answer below. As for the class-as-purely-a-namespace thing, just use a regular object literal with properties, this isn't Java. As for the create a new instance hack, I would need more details to give a better suggestion but off the cuff I would recommend giving your instances a clone method perhaps? Your method in that function only works if you know the arguments to the constructor (or if it doesn't take any), but if you know that you can just call it directly.

Comment: Ok, I just tried this and as pointed out in the answer below. This doesn't work for deeply nested fields. Any solution for those situations as well?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this answers the question but you may be able to set the properties BaseGameMode as `readonly` to prevent modifications.

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html#readonly-modifier

Or use the `ReadOnly` utility type for the object to set its properties to readonly (but it does not affect deeply nested fields).

https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

This way the client is forced to copy the object if they want to modify it.

However, it may be easier to just return a deep-copy/clone like you are doing if the client is going to make a lot of modifications to the object.

Comment: Will readonly work in things like arrays and objects? It might not

Comment: @Esqarrouth It works only one level deep, for deeply nested objects, maybe this answer helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879327/deepreadonly-object-typescript