# BehaviorSubject: mutating current value between subscriptions

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

Assume I have BehaviorSubject with User interface:

```
interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
}

let user: User = {
  firstName: 'Cuong',
  lastName: 'Le',
};

let bs = new BehaviorSubject<User>(user);
```

There are two subsciptions, `sub1` tried to change the first name. `Sub2` subscribes later and user object has first name changed also as the `sub1` did change it before:

```
let sub1 = bs.subscribe((u) => {
  u.firstName = 'An';

  console.log(u);
});

let sub2 = bs.subscribe((u) => {
  console.log(u);
});
```

it's hard to debug when this case happens in big Angular application. How we make the value immutable when subscribing?

I am looking deep immutable solution to prevent code somewhere else to change the data instead of the shadow one

Comment: This surprised me - but is indeed possible. More here: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/master-rxjs-data-stores-in-services-c1f553e5d48b

Answer (score 2):

You can use the utility type [`Readonly<T>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#readonlytype) to mark the type on the BehaviorSubject as `Readonly<User>` instead of `User`:

```js
let bs = new BehaviorSubject<Readonly<User>>(user);
```

Now, TS will warn you when you try to modify:

[image: screenshot]

> Cannot assign to 'firstName' because it is a read-only property. (2540)

Comment: How does it work with Property level 2?

Comment: Good point, this will not warn when assigning nested properties.  You may find [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41879327/deepreadonly-object-typescript) and this [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/13923) of interest.  They mention some ways to implement a `DeepReadonly<T>`.

Answer (score 1):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58993872/2497335) and wrapping your type in this Immutable utility type should solve your problem.  Unlike the **readonly** keyword or **ReadOnly** utility type, the **Immutable** interface in this answer will recursively makes all properties read only.

```
interface User {
  firstName: string;
  lastName: string;
  address: { 
    street: string;
  } 
}

let user: User = {
  firstName: 'Cuong',
  lastName: 'Le',
  address: { 
    street: '123 Sesame St.'
  }
};

let bs = new BehaviorSubject<Immutable<User>>(user);

let sub1 = bs.subscribe((u) => {
  u.address.street = '456'; //<-- Cannot assign to 'street' because it is a read-only property.
  console.log(u);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, How does it work with Property level 2?

Comment: Got an answer that should work with nested properties.

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem I've had to solve several times. As long as you are passing simple non-circular objects through the subject this solution should work.

The one requirement is that you utilize the [lodash](https://lodash.com) library, which supports a very fast deep copy (no reference copies). I've looked everywhere and I've yet to find one that is faster.

```
let bs = (new BehaviorSubject<User>(user)).pipe(    
     map((userData) => _.cloneDeep(userData)) 
);
```

I've used this on fairly large state objects and I've always been impressed by how quickly it is able to perform copies. The implication here is that any emission coming out of the subject is a copy of the original, so changes happen in isolation and will never be able to trail back to the source.

Comment: Is there any solution without using lodash?

Comment: Sure. Instead of using cloneDeep, just create a new object and manually copy all the values over. I'd take lodash any day over doing it manually.