# How to prevent the mutation of nested prop fields in Vue 3, using TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, immutability, vue-props

Suppose I have the following SFC component:

```js
<script setup lang="ts">
export interface Person {
  name: string;
}

const props = defineProps<{
  person: Person;
}>();

function onClick(): void {
  props.person.name = 'Joe'; // mutate nested field
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="onClick">Click</button>
</template>
```

How can I prevent the mutation of the nested prop field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the readonly modifier to make the props readonly. This will ensure that the props cannot be mutated within the component.

```
<script setup lang="ts">
export interface Person {
  name: string;
  address: {
    city: string;
    street: string;
  };
}

type DeepReadonly<T> = {
  readonly [K in keyof T]: DeepReadonly<T[K]>;
};

const props = defineProps<{
  person: DeepReadonly<Person>;
}>();

function onClick(): void {
  // TypeScript error: Cannot assign to 'name' because it is a read-only property
  props.person.name = 'Joe';

  // TypeScript error: Cannot assign to 'city' because it is a read-only property
  props.person.address.city = 'New City';
}
</script>

<template>
  <button @click="onClick">Click</button>
</template>
```

Comment: This works for the first level only, further nested levels are still mutable. Any way to make it work for all levels?

Comment: you can use DeepReadonly like my edited code, that way all nested props would be okay

Comment: [This implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58993872/6923555) of deep readonly is more comprehensive, but other than that, your solution works. Thank you.

Comment: Consider freeze and deep freeze